# Windex and Red wine

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

The other day I was cleaning my counter tops with windex. There was a couple red wine (cabernet sauvignon if it makes a difference) stains from the night before and the stains turned an gray/blue color upon being sprayed with the windex. What is the cause of the color change? Is it simply the blue windex mixing with the red wine?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Arguably, _most_ organic colors are pH indicators.

Comment: Red cabbage soup goes through similar color changes (though I'm not sure if it is best served with meat or with fish).